# Position of close button on CSS pop up

Tags: css, popup

I have a thumbnail image you can click to open a full size image as a pop up div.

I want the close button for that pop up to be in the top right corner on the border but not on the image itself. I've attached a screenshot example from another site of what I am trying to do, as well as an example of what mine looks like.

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')"><img src="images/close.png" align=right></a><img src="images/largeimg.jpg" width=551 height=750>
    </div>  
  <h1><a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click Here To Open The Pop Up</a></h1>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 9001; 
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
}

#popUpDiv {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    width:551px;
    height:779px;
border:10px solid white;
    z-index: 9002; 
}
```

How can I move the close button so that it is on the border and not causing that extra white space due to the button image height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/xMe62/)**

**CSS**

```
#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   position:fixed;
   z-index: 9001; 
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#popUpDiv {
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
    width:551px;
    margin:10% auto 0 auto;
    height:259px;
border:10px solid white;
    z-index: 9002; 

}
.close{position:absolute; right:-25px; top:-25px;}
```

​

Answer (score 4):

Don't re-invent the wheel. The screenshot you provided looks a lot like [fancy box](http://fancybox.net/). A [jquery](http://jquery.com/) plug in. Use that instead. You will save your self cross browser headaches using this or one of the mainy other similar jQuery plugins.

Comment: good advice, thanks for the link. I may end up using fancy box instead if I run into any other problems